# Running thread in background in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class with a connect_to method which I'm starting a thread in it, after calling it and joining it, I expected the thread to run in the background and the program execution would continue but it hangs in my `connect_to` method until the thread execution stops. I remember I used to work with threads in C# and they ran in the background once I started them.

```
#ifndef _TCP_CLIENT_H_
#define _TCP_CLIENT_H_

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

void connection_thread(void *user);


class TCPClient
{

public:
    SOCKET                m_ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    char                  m_recvbuf[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    int                   m_recvbuflen = BUFFER_LENGTH;
    struct addrinfo*      m_result = NULL, *m_ptr = NULL, m_hints;
    vector<PacketInfo*>   m_packet_list;
    PacketInfo*           m_packet_data = new PacketInfo();
    thread*               m_conn_thread;

    int state = 0;
    char* ip_address;
    unsigned int port = 0;

    TCPClient() {}
    ~TCPClient() {
        delete m_packet_data;
    }


    int Init_Sockets() {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult;

        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }



    int Connect_to(char* ip, unsigned int port_number) {
        port = port_number;
        ip_address = ip;

        //thread conn_thread(connection_thread, this);
                thread conn_thread([=]() {connection_thread(this); return 1; });
        conn_thread.join();



        state = 0;
        return 1;
    }


}; // end TCPClient class




void connection_thread(void *user) {
    TCPClient * self = static_cast<TCPClient*>(user);


        // connecting code here... //


    self->state = CONNECTED;
    do {

        iResult = recv(self->m_ConnectSocket, self->m_recvbuf, self->m_recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0) {
            printf("Connection closed\n");
            self->state = DISCONNECTED;
        }
        else {
            //printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }

    }
    while (iResult > 0);
}

#endif
```

The thread works as intended and is on a constant loop until the connection closes. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hanging because the call to `join()` cause the current thread to be paused until the joining thread finishes at which point the call to `join()` will return.

```
 conn_thread.join();   // Current thread will wait
                       // until conn_thread finishes.
```

You also mention in comments that if you don't do the join then you get an abort called. This is because the destructor of thread calls `terminate()` if the thread it represents is still `joinble`.

Since your thread object is local it is destroyed at the end of the call to `Connect_to()`.

```
int Connect_to(char* ip, unsigned int port_number) {

    // Here you have defined a variable local to the function
    // Thus its constructor is called here (which starts the thread)
    thread conn_thread([=]() {connection_thread(this); return 1; });


    // conn_thread.join();
}
    // The destructor is called here.
    // If the thread is still running at this point you will
    // get a call to `terminate()`
```

So how do you stop that.

1. You can call the `detach()` method.
2. You can make `thread` belong to larger context so it is not destroyed.

Calling `detach()` is not a good idea. As you loose all reference to the running thread and communication with it becomes hard.

I also notice that you have a member in your `class TCPClient`

```
thread*               m_conn_thread;
```

This does not seem to be used.
If you store your thread in this object it will last as long as the object (thus longer than the function). The object is obviously supposed to last as long as the thread since the thread access members of the object.

So I would make the following changes:

```
 // 1 Make the member a real variable not a pointer.
 std::thread               m_conn_thread;

 // 2 Initialize this in the constructor.
 TCPClient()
    : m_conn_thread()   // no thread created with this constructor.
 {}

 // 3 Create and assing a thread to this variable.
 int Connect_to(char* ip, unsigned int port_number) {
      // STUFF
      m_conn_thread = std::move(std::thread([=]() {connection_thread(this); return 1; }));
      // MORE STUFF
  }

  // Add a destructor that waits for the thread to join.
  ~TCPClient()
  {
      // As the thread is using members from this object
      // We can not let this obect be destroyed until
      // the thread finishes executing.
      m_conn_thread.join();

      // At this point the thread has finished.
      // Destructor can now complete.



       // Note: Without the join.
       //       This could potentially call terminate()
       //       as destroying the member m_conn_thread while the
       //       the thread is still running is bad.
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!I was kicking myself after realizing that i initialized the thread in another scope.

Answer (score 7):

> I have a class with a connect_to method which i'm starting a thread in it, **after** calling it and **joining it**, i expected the thread to run in the background and the program execution would continue but **it hangs in my connect_to method until the thread execution stops**

That's literally what joining a thread is supposed to do!

If you don't want to join to the thread, then simply don't. :)

Though, probably, you should at least do it in your class destructor or at some other later time, so that your main thread cannot try to end while the worker thread is still executing. Because that will end in tears...

It seems to me that this is a perfect example of why we should not write lines of code with no understanding as to *why* we're doing so. :) You've made an assumption about what `conn_thread.join()` means, an assumption that is wrong: one of the first things to do in this situation is to *read the documentation* to make sure your assumptions hold. Ideally you'd have read it *before* writing the code, but never mind.

Comment: Unfortunately if i don't join it, i get an error box: Debug error! R6010 - abort() has been called.

Comment: @Skrakle: That is not a reason to join it (whose documented purpose is literally the opposite of what you want to do). That is a reason to find out why `abort()` has been called. Anyway, the reason is _probably_ what I said in my third paragraph...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sometimes, trial and error leads to the understanding of why. Depending on the learning style of the person, they may have to explore the code by writing it to understand how it behaves, thus understanding if and or why they need it (or dont). Its not necessarily a bad thing if the end results are both the same: the user understood what they need to do and why.

Comment: @Javia1492: All fine and good but still no excuse not to read the documentation either before programming or whilst baffled about your program not working as expected. This is not "trial and error"; this is "trial and ask for help".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, i agree. Blindly going into it saying "oh well its not working" is not correct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sadly there's a *ton* of libraries out there with very very poor documentation. It's unfortunately often easier to just read the library's code if available or else use trial-and-error if not.

Comment: I don't know if you guys are assuming that i didn't read any documentation about it but i've been at it for hours and started here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/ and as Javia1492 stated, i've been trying everything i can to see what does what which is why i didn't comment join which is the only thing that works right now or else i'm getting a abort.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So any idea why the thread gets aborted after following your fantastic advice by removing join (which i initially did...)?

Comment: @inetknght: Easier if your goal is to produce code; harder if your goal is to produce code that _works_.

Comment: This was my problem all along:
    thread conn_thread([=]() {connection_thread(this); return 1; });
should be:
    conn_thread([=]() {connection_thread(this); return 1; });

I re-declared a new thread variable by mistake in connect_to method.

Comment: @Skrakle: Ehm so where do you declare it now?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: At the top of my class as a member. I was declaring a new one with the same name in connect_to which is ended up being destroyed after exiting the connect method.

Comment: @Skrakle: Okay, so that's exactly what I said in my third paragraph: you were letting the thread object go out of scope before joining to it. "Fantastic advice" indeed, it seems! (And the reason I couldn't see what you meant is that the member is _actually_ called `m_conn_thread`, not `conn_thread` as you suggested in your comment. :P)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't make anything much of your third paragraph because i knew i wasn't exiting main and my problem was not halting the thread but rather to keep it going, still good advice. As for your fourth paragraph, you might want to work on your assumption skills a little as i do a lot of reading before asking for help, it just turned out my that mistake was just plain silly and had nothing to do with not understanding threads and i did mention i worked with them before. :)

Comment: @Skrakle: My assumption was spot on.